# Alternatives to " " for creating strings containing multiple whitespace characters

Tags: c#, string, spaces

I'm wondering if there's a more OO way of creating spaces in C#.

Literally Space Code!

I currently have `tabs += new String(" ");` and I can't help but feel that this is somewhat reminiscent of using `""` instead of `String.Empty`.

What can I use to create spaces that isn't `" "`?

Comment: And there's nothing wrong with `""` rather than `string.Empty` either.

Comment: I don't think there's anything "wrong" as such. I'm just wondering if there's another way to do it that's perhaps more...OO...dare i say.

Comment: There's nothing inherently OO or non-OO about using " " or a named constant.

Comment: Part of the reason for this question is that I've recently joined a new team. The lead architect pulled me up on a few occasions for using "" instead of String.Empty and I wanted to know if there was another way of doing spaces before he gets chance to pull me up on that. Now I know i'll stick with using String(" ",numOfSpaces). Thanks everyone for your replies!

Comment: (insert mandatory 'use StringBuilder' remark here)

Comment: @Luke: I believe that String.Empty is a fixed reference while using "" actually creates a new object that will then have to be GCed, but now I can't remember where I read that.

Comment: @Joe. In fact all instances of "" in the source code will point to the same string, due to interning. According to Tony The Pony at least. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html

Comment: @Joe, @MarkJ: Also take a look at this article and its comments: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/09/28/string-interning-and-string-empty.aspx

Comment: Apologies for changing the title, but the new one might make it easier to search for in future.

Comment: I wish it was built into .net framework string.Space(); string.Space(int repeat);

Comment: StringBuilder.Insert and StringBuilder.Append allow you to create any number spaces, e.g. sb.Insert(0, " ", 20) will insert 20 spaces to the start of your sb (StringBuilder) object.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can write

```
" "
```

instead of

```
new String(' ')
```

Does that help?

---

Depending on what you do, you might want to look into the [StringBuilder.Append](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxyxbz2e.aspx) overload that accepts a character and a 'repeat' count:

```
var tabs = new StringBuilder();
tabs.Append(' ', 8);
```

or into the `string` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w.aspx) that constructs a string from a character a 'repeat' count:

```
var tabs = new string(' ', 8);
```

---

Here's an enterprisey OO solution to satisfy all your space generation needs:

```
public abstract class SpaceFactory
{
    public static readonly SpaceFactory Space = new SpaceFactoryImpl();

    public static readonly SpaceFactory ZeroWidth = new ZeroWidthFactoryImpl();

    protected SpaceFactory { }

    public abstract char GetSpace();

    public virtual string GetSpaces(int count)
    {
        return new string(this.GetSpace(), count);
    }

    private class SpaceFactoryImpl : SpaceFactory
    {
        public override char GetSpace()
        {
            return '\u0020';
        }
    }

    private class ZeroWidthFactoryImpl : SpaceFactory
    {
        public override char GetSpace()
        {
            return '\u200B';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my actual code I'm doing new String(' ',numberOfSpaces) so I probably need to still use the new String part.

Comment: @Jamie: It would have been useful to say that to start with, as it makes basically all the existing answers invalid.

Comment: Yeah appologies for that. I think other people might have this question at some point, and those people might not be specifying the number of spaces so I think these answers will be useful for them.

Comment: Thanks dtb. I had to accept this one, not only because you answered the question at the top, but also for your use of the terms "SpaceFactory" and "enterprisey".

Comment: @dtb I changed the title as there is an almost identical question this evening, but I tried to leave the original reference to SpaceCode in to preserve context for this very amusing answer. To quote your avatar, "Oh No!"

Answer (score 15):

Now that you've clarified in comments:

> In my actual code I'm doing new
>   String(' ',numberOfSpaces) so I
>   probably need to still use the new
>   String part.

... the other answers so far are effectively useless :(

You *could* write:

```
const char Space = ' ';
```

then use

```
new string(Space, numberOfSpaces)
```

but I don't see any benefit of that over

```
new string(' ', numberOfSpaces)
```

Answer (score 8):

if the number of spaces would be changing then you could do something like this:

```
public static string Space(int count)
{
    return "".PadLeft(count);
}

Space(2);
```

Comment: Nice, but I'd use String.Empty to satisfy his dislike of strings in code!

Comment: Or use the string constructor that takes a character count instead: `return new string(' ', count);`

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason to do this. All else being equal, [smaller code is better code](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000878.html). `String.Empty` and `new String(' ')` communicate the same thing as `""` and `" "`, they just take more characters to do it.

Trying to make it 'more OO' just adds characters for no benefit. Object-Orientation is not an end in itself.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how prevalent this is in your code, the StringBuilder way may be better.

```
StringBuilder tabs = new StringBuilder();
...

tabs.Append(" ");
```

You can mix in the constant too...

```
StringBuilder tabs = new StringBuilder();
const string SPACE = " ";
...

tabs.Append(SPACE);
```

Answer (score 3):

Extend string to give you a method to add space

```
public static string AddSpace(this String text, int size)
{
   return text + new string(' ', size)
}
```

Awful in it's own right though.

Comment: +1 - extension methods seem to be in line with the OP's style here. Note you can replace the body of this function with `return new String(' ', count);` as this overloaded constructor does exactly what you've done :)

Comment: Even though an extension method may be desired, there's no need to use repeated string concatenation like this. "return text + new string(' ', size)" would be more appropriate IMO. (Having changed the first parameter from the keyword `string` to `text`...)

Comment: Thanks John and Jon (sorry Tony). Yes that feels much better, being a web bod I rarely want to have two spaces next to each other anyway, just thought I'd add my two pence worth.

Answer (score 2):

The more "OO" way would be to find a simpler way of solving your larger business problem. For example, the fact that you have a variable named `tabs` suggests to me that you are trying to roll your own column alignment code. `String.Format` supports that directly, e.g.

```
// Left-align name and status, right-align amount (formatted as currency).
writer.WriteLine("Name                 Status         Amount");
writer.WriteLine("-------------------- ---------- ----------");
foreach(var item in items) {
    writer.WriteLine(string.Format("{0,-20} {1,-10} {2,10:C}", item.Name, item.Status, item.Amount));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Christian. The larger problem i'm solving is that I've got an IEnumerable of objects with an Id and ParentId. I'm outputting the contents of these objects to CSV format for data export and need to show the relationship between the objects. On the screen they're shown as a Tree grid and for export I'm spacing them to show the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

If the language allowed for it you could add an extension property to the type String which was Space, something like:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public static char Space(this String s)
    {
        get {
            return ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

but that isn't possible.  I think it would be better to keep the space inside the property if it was a localizable thingy, but I think spaces are universal across all languages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are taking OO way to far.. A simple addition of a space does not need an entire class.

```
tabs += new String(' ');
```

or

```
tabs += " ";
```

is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `"\t"`, I think, to give you a tab character. That might make the spaceing more clear.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder.Insert and StringBuilder.Append allow you to create any number spaces, e.g. sb.Insert(0, " ", 20) will insert 20 spaces to the start of your sb (StringBuilder) object.

Answer (score 0):

You may create class extensions.

```
public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static string GetSpace(this String)
        {
           return " ";
        }
    }
```

and you can call this.

```
String.GetSPace();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use string.Empty.PadLeft(8) for example