# Elegant way to make whitespace string

Tags: c#, .net

Is there an elegant way to make **whitespace** string.
To be more precise, I'm looking for solution similar to following:

For an empty string I could write

```
string emptyString = "";
```

but instead I use this far more discriptive way

```
string emptyString = string.Empty;
```

Comment: “far more descriptive” what are you smoking? How isn’t `""` perfectly descriptive?! The only distinction is that `string.Empty` is six times as much code.

Comment: You could create one: `public const String WhiteSpace = " ";`

Comment: While there is a great variety among witespace strings, there could possibly be only one empty string.

Comment: you can define your own constant for a space if needed. As what i know .net doesn't define it for you since a space can be a blankspace or even a tab...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Actually that is only true as of .NET 2.0 iirc.  Before that not all instances of `""` referred to the same interned string.

Comment: Also, I would argue that `string.Empty` is no more descriptive than `""`.  I mean really, when has `""` ever confused anyone?  You can easily go down the crazy path with this stuff.

Comment: Following the comment from @dasblinkenlight, look at this MSDN on [Char.IsWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx.aspx) method. As you can see, there are numerous characters that qualifies as 'whitespace'. That's one of the reasons why you need a method and not a constant.

Comment: This is very similar to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716230/space-code-in-c-sharp

Comment: I think he meant, easier / quicker to read.  I find myself having to do a double take when reading code to see if it's " " or "" when I see string.Empty there is no doubt.

Comment: @orn: Really?  I can't say I have ever had to give more than 1/16 of a nono-second worth of thought to figure out if a string constant is `" "` or `""`.  Perhaps you require a larger font?

Comment: @EdS.  lol, that might be my problem, I will try the larger font, thnx

Comment: I asked this because I thought if string.Empty exists why shouldn't there be string.Space or something like that... That's all.

Comment: @orn We know what he meant. I still find it ridiculous. If you do a double-take when reading `""` or `" "` may I suggest you use a mono-spaced font? There can be no confusing the two, even at a glance. No other programming language defines a constant for empty strings. Apparently those programmers have no problem reading `""` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I prefer using `""` over `string.Empty`, but there's nothing stopping you from writing a string constants class:

```
public static class Strings
{
    public const string Space = " ";
}

...

string whitespace = Strings.Space;
```

(Note that I haven't called it `Whitespace`, as that would be ambiguous - a tab character is whitespace, for example.)

Can't say I've ever had much use for such a class though...

Answer (score 2):

I find this extremely elegant:

```
string singleSpace = " ";
```

Seems perfectly expressive to me.

Comment: I do not know why you mentioned the Ruby here. Another way to do it in C# is by using String constructor: `new string(' ', 10)` or if you/he prefer `new String(' ', 10);` or yet `new String((Char)0x20, 10)` some people said that it faster -- but I haven't tested.

Comment: @Jack: eh, I don't know either, this question just made me think of it.  What I did not realize is that there existed a String constructor to do that, so thanks.

Comment: The `StringBuilder` class provide a similar method too; just pass the number of repetitions into second parameter of `.Append()` where the first is of `char` type: `var foo = new StringBuilder().Append(' ', 10);` and then call `.ToString()` to get a `string` of 10 white-spaces. But I do not know if it is faster that a `string` constructor call, it is only another way how to do it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I make single character long strings (usually for banking position-based files):

```
string absurdlyLongWhiteSpaceString = string.Empty.PadLeft(500);
```

Or '0' filled strings for empty numeric values:

```
string absurdlyLongZeroedString = string.Empty.PadLeft(500, '0');
```

Hope this helps.