# C# How do I put spaces between each character without using the space bar

Tags: c#, character, space

The output needs to have spaces between each character so it should be like '? e m a n r u o y s 
i t a h W' and not like "emanruoysitahw'. How do I do this with the code I have already written. Thanks for any help.

```
using System;


namespace strings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
           string inString= "What is your name?",outString="";

           foreach(char c in inString)
           {
           outString = c + outString;
           }
          {
          Console.WriteLine("" + outString);
          }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We help with problems in your code and not taking your requirements and writing the code for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to " " for creating strings containing multiple whitespace characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716230/alternatives-to-for-creating-strings-containing-multiple-whitespace-characte)

Comment: I have googled my it but I can't find anything that works.

Comment: @reg Sure looks like homework to me. It's a good idea to make an attempt at solving your problem rather than just asking people to solve it for you. You'll learn better that way (whether it's homework or not).

Comment: I think we should all help newbies and I rarely downvote. But this is clearly homework. Shame on you for posting this!

Comment: @reg Look into putting your characters into an array and then [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it with space as the separator as one possible approach.

Comment: @reg: You have outstring that you are adding to character by character. Why not just add your spaces there too? I'm confused as to whether there is something I missed that means this obvious solution won't work...

Comment: Also can you clarify your requirement of "without using the space bar". Do you mean you aren't allowed to have the character `' '` in your code anywhere or just that you don't want to put the spaces in the original string?

Answer (score 7):

You could:

```
 outString = string.Join(" ", input.ToCharArray());
```

Comment: +1. (not very serious comment) The only possible improvement to match "no spacebar" could be to replace `" "` with `"\x20"` :) - than whole program can be typed without ever pressing space.

Answer (score 1):

The improper (and inefficient) way most of us use:

```
outString += c + "\x26";
```

The proper (yet inefficient) way most of us **dont't** use:

```
outString.Insert(c + "\x26");
```

The proper and efficient way smart programmers use

```
var s = new StringBuilder();
s.append(c + "\x26");
outString = s.ToString();
```

Wait. You don't have a space bar do you? Use this:

```
StringBuilder(s)=new
StringBuilder();
s.append(c+"\x26");
outString=s.ToString();
```

How on earth is this a real life situation anyway?

Comment: I'd probably avoid the string concatenation if I was going down that route in favour of `StringBuilder`, particularly as the string has an indeterminate length...

Comment: It's a good idea *not* to answer right away if it looks like a homework question. Instead, you should make sure they've made an attempt to solve the problem before just explaining how to do it.

Comment: @Joeb454 I agree with you, but the OP doesn't know how to add a **space** to a string..

Comment: I reckon you probably used the space bar though I will concede that you may have just copy and pasted the space from somewhere else... :)

Comment: @mason this is just flat out not a good answer (also not completely bad, so no -1): building long string with string concatenation is just bad idea.

Comment: @Chris you can also do alt + 255 for a space. That way you don't press space bar.

Comment: @deathismyfriend: alt+32 would be a more traditional space I believe (255 being a non-breaking space I believe).

Comment: @Chris No need for the space bar anymore :)

Comment: @RandomUser: Did you mean `\x20` in that code? Also you can use line a line break between `new` and `StringBuilder` instead of a space if you wanted. OtherwiseGoodJob.ILikeIt.:)